# In SwiftUI, how do I remove a view stuck on top of the keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, keyboard, swift-keyboard

I have a view under a Form. When I enter a text field the view is stuck on top of the keyboard.

Code in question:

```
  // other stuff

  Form {
    Section {
      TextField("Enter your desired username", text: $page.username)
    }
    
    Section {
      Button(action: createUser) {
        Label("Sign Up", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
      }
    }
  }
  
  // this is getting stuck on top of keyboard
  Group {
    Text("By signing up you agree to")
    // other stuff
  }
```

What it looks like:

[image: Bug in question]

As you can see, the "By signing up you..." view is stuck on top of the keyboard. I suspect it has something to do with Menu.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: "view is stuck on top of the keyboard"  It's a form, not a list.  So what's the problem?

Comment: How about puttin it in a zstack? and post more code so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Form and Group inside some other container, like a VStack? I assume you must… if so, the solution is to add `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)` to that container.

e.g.,

```swift
VStack {
    Form {
        ...
    }
    Group {
        ...
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
```

Applying `ignoresSafeArea` to the Group doesn’t work because its container (here a VStack) is still resized by the keyboard. If adding `ignoresSafeArea` to your container has undesirable consequences, please post more of your code so we can understand the situation.